java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.el.ELAwareBeanManager
I am currently migrating a project from Java 11 to Java 17, Spring 5 to Spring 6, and from RichFaces to PrimeFaces 14 (Jakarta). After making the necessary changes, I am encountering the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityBean': Invocation of init method failed
    at com.leo.service-ui.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityBean': Invocation of init method failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at com.leo.service-ui.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/enterprise/inject/spi/el/ELAwareBeanManager
    at jakarta.faces.CurrentThreadToServletContext.getFactoryFinder(CurrentThreadToServletContext.java:52)
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:257)
    at jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(FacesContext.java:872)
    at com.leo.service-ui.util.FacesUtil.getRequestParameter(FacesUtil.java:28)
    at com.leo.service-ui.ui.beans.EntityBean.init(EntityBean.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMethod.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:219)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.el.ELAwareBeanManager
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 28 more

Project Details:

Java Version: 17
Spring Version: 6
PrimeFaces Version: 14 (Jakarta)
Build Tool: Maven

pom.xml
:
<dependencies>
    <!-- Other existing dependencies -->

    <!-- Jakarta EE dependencies -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.6</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0-RC2</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

Code Snippet:
Here is the relevant code where the exception occurs:
public class FacesUtil {
    public static String getRequestParameter(String paramName) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); // Exception occurs here
        Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        return params.getOrDefault(paramName, null);
    }
}

What I've Tried:

Verified that all necessary Jakarta EE dependencies are included in

pom.xml
.
2. Ensured that the weld-servlet-shaded dependency is present.
3. Added the jakarta.jakartaee-api dependency with provided scope.
Question:
What could be causing this java.lang.ClassNotFoundException and how can I resolve it? Are there any additional dependencies or configurations required when migrating to Java 17, Spring 6, and PrimeFaces 14 (Jakarta)?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Can you show the full stack trace?

Are you sure 11.0.0-M4  is correct for EE as that is EE11 not EE10?

@AndreySmelik - Added full stacktrace.

@Melloware downgraded to use 10.0.0. Still facing same issue

Spring Boot supports only JakartaEE 10 (it isn't compatible with JakartaEE11). The class that is missing is part of JakartaEE  11 (CDI 4.1 that is). So you are currently containing a mix of libraries from various JakartaEE versions. Downgrade to the versions that belong to JakartaEE 10.


java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.el.ELAwareBeanManager

This class was since CDI 4.1 (Jakarta EE 11, which Faces 4.1 is also part of) split from the core CDI API into a supplemental CDI API artifact: jakarta.cdi.el. See also CDI 4.1 specification section "Major Changes":

CDI 4.1 no longer specifies integration with Jakarta EE. This will now be specified in the Jakarta EE Platform, Web Profile and Core Profile specifications.
The Unified EL integration API in BeanManager has been deprecated and the relevant methods added to a dedicated interface ELAwareBeanManager, which is present in a new supplemental API artifact: jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-el-api.

So, in other words, in case you target a barebones servletcontainer such as Tomcat instead of a real Jakarta EE compatible server, then the following CDI 4.1 API dependency,
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

needs to be extended as follows:
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-el-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

The alternative in your specific case is to simply bump your existing weld-servlet-shaded dependency from 5.x to 6.x as that already transitively(!) includes the correct API classes. It's currently only still in the beta:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0.Beta4</version>
</dependency>

Do note that the transitive inclusion thus means that you can safely drop the CDI API and CDI-EL API dependencies from your pom.xml in order to keep it simple.
Unrelated to the concrete problem, I see you also have a "provided" Jakarta EE 10 dependency. This is not entirely correct when you're targeting a barebones servletcontainer instead of a certified Jakarta EE runtime. Please refer to the following links how to correctly sort out it.
See also:

How to properly configure Jakarta EE libraries in Maven pom.xml for Tomcat?
How to install and use CDI on Tomcat?

